# SQL Server - sys.dm_exec_sql_text.sql_handle showing constant CREATE PROCEDURE - how to prove it

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have questioned the code of one of our vendors.  When running this basic script:

```
SELECT  top 20
   qt.text,
   qs.creation_time,
   qs.plan_generation_num,
qs.execution_count, 
qs.last_execution_time,
qp.query_plan
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
WHERE 
    qt.encrypted = 0
    and qt.text like '%CREATE PROCEDURE%'
ORDER BY 
    qs.execution_count DESC
```

I see the following results:

[sql query output - top 20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQcOZ.png)

But, when i run SQL profiler, looking for SP:recompile, I haven't seen anything at all.  It looks like the SP is being recompiled hundreds of times per minutes, but I only have the proof from my script.

In researching this issue, this afternoon, I found some SQL pages that said that having SET ANSI_NULLS ON and SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON could trigger a recompile, but I couldn't find enough either way on that.

I am also including the code from one of the SPs in the output.

Am I missing something here?  There is no question that the SP is being executed hundreds of times per minute, but is it being recompiled as well?

Thank you!

Stored Procedure code:

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[stMessageQueueDequeue]    Script 
Date: 5/11/2017 4:14:56 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stMessageQueueDequeue]
(
  @pDestination varchar(100)
)
AS

BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Select du message a envoyer selon la Priority et DateAdded
declare 
@TopMessageId int,
@priority int

select @priority = min(priority) from messagequeue
where  Retry < 5 AND Destination = @pDestination AND DateNextRetry <= 
GetUtcDate()

select top 1 @TopMessageId = id from messagequeue
where  Retry < 5 AND Destination = @pDestination AND DateNextRetry <= 
GetUtcDate() AND priority = @priority
ORDER BY Retry,  DateNextRetry,DateAdded 

IF @@ERROR <> 0
  BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RETURN -1
  END

IF @TopMessageId IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN

        UPDATE MessageQueue 
        SET DateProcessed = GetUtcDate(), 
        Retry = Retry + 1,
        DateNextRetry=
              CASE 
                    WHEN Retry=0 THEN    DATEADD(minute, 5 , GetUtcDate())
              when Retry=1   THEN DATEADD(minute, 20 ,  GetUtcDate())
              when Retry=2   THEN DATEADD(minute, 60 ,  GetUtcDate())
              when Retry=3   THEN DATEADD(minute, 80 ,  GetUtcDate())
              when Retry=4   THEN DATEADD(minute, 720 ,  GetUtcDate())
              ELSE   DATEADD(minute, 1440 ,  GetUtcDate())
              END 
        WHERE HashCode = (select top 1 HashCode from MessageQueue where   id 
        = @TopMessageId)

        IF @@ERROR <> 0
              BEGIN
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                    RETURN -1
              END

        SELECT id, Source, Destination, Message, HashCode, DateAdded, 
        Priority, Retry, DateProcessed, DateNextRetry from messagequeue
        where id = @TopMessageId
        IF @@ERROR <> 0
              BEGIN
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                    RETURN -1
              END

        END




 declare @vLastDate as datetime 

 SELECT @vLastDate  = Value from STatus where [key] = 
 'MessagequeueHistoryLastPurge'
 IF @vLastDate is null 
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO STATUS ([Key] , value ) 
 values ( 'MessagequeueHistoryLastPurge' ,'2000-01-01' ) 
 SET @vLastDate  = '2000-01-01'
 END 


 IF DATEDIFF(d ,  @vLastDate,GETUTCDATE() ) > 1  
 BEGIN 
 DELETE MessageQueueHistory WHERE DateProcessed <  DATEADD(d ,  -7, 
 GETUTCDATE() ) 
 UPDATE STATUS set Value = GETUTCDATE() where [key] = 
 'MessagequeueHistoryLastPurge'
 EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'IF ''?'' LIKE ''%Audit%'' BEGIN truncate table ? 
 END'
 END



COMMIT TRANSACTION
RETURN 0
```

Comment: No it isn't being recompiled. When a proc is being executed that is what is normally shown.

Comment: Then why does my code show the "CREATE PROCEDURE" bit.  Is that coming from the cache from the very first compilation, but after that it was just executing?

Comment: Because for stored procedures that DMV returns the complete object definition and it is part of the definition. You use `statement_start_offset` etc to see the part that is being executed.

Comment: Ok thank you.  I looked quite a bit yesterday and was unable to find such a concise answer.